# Swift 2 -- Multiple view controllers for different devices

Tags: swift, autolayout, swift2

Is this possible? I would love to create multiple view controllers for each apple device. I know I could go in and add constraints to make all my labels and buttons line up properly, but after about 4 hours of messing with constraints and watching tutorials, I just can't get it right! Is there any possible way to just create multiple view controllers for each device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and I have done it before, but I wouldn't recommend it. I did that when AutoLayout was introduced and it all seemed too hard. I returned to AutoLayout when Apple introduced [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html). They make life much easier to have very different constraints for different devices. They also handle things like an iPhone 6 Plus being pretty much as big as an iPad mini.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably spend a lot of time hacking away at making a work around for not being able to use auto-layout but you would definitely end up spending more time in the long run.

I struggled a lot with auto-layout when I started (and still wouldn't say i'm an expert) but after spending some time reading the millions of different tutorials I found it much easier.

It's difficult to recommend different sources for training material like this because everyone has a different preferred style. It's easy to recommend the official Apple docs (Auto Layout: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) but they can be so verbose that frankly, you end up getting bored and/or daunted so give up. Some people love youtube videos and some love blogs.

It's up to you to find a guide that helps but if you come back on Stack overflow with clearly explained, small and simple examples of UI elements that you are trying to manage with auto layout then people might try and explain what approach you should take and these instructions will come in different formats.